# Is there a function in MATLAB that converts a .raw file into a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io, image-formats

I want to import a .raw file into MATLAB as a matrix (frames x spatial x spectral). Is there a built-in function to do this?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the *.raw format you refer to?  The heading somewhat hints at it perhaps being a raw image sequence, but it's hard to be certain.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to a [raw image file from a camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format), I would check out the submission [RAW Camera File Reader](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7412) from [Bryan White](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/17947) on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/).

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. Do you know of any others?

Comment: @flywtink: It would be helpful if you could tell me exactly *where* (i.e. what sort of device) you are getting your .raw files from.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the file directly. But you'll need to convert it to DNG first. See this: 
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/03/08/tips-for-reading-a-camera-raw-file-into-matlab/