# Can matlab read an image file stored in *.raw format

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a function in MATLAB that converts a .raw file into a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210612/is-there-a-function-in-matlab-that-converts-a-raw-file-into-a-matrix)

I have a image stored in .raw format. I would like to read it with matlab. Is it possible?
If not, what shld i do such that matlab can read .raw format?

Comment: RAW format is not a single format.  You might want to specify what device this image comes from.

Comment: my prof just passed me a image with raw format.. how to find which device it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

There is a SO topic you can check out. [Is there a function in MATLAB that converts a .raw file into a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210612/is-there-a-function-in-matlab-that-converts-a-raw-file-into-a-matrix) .
Also you can check *multibandread*.